# relation between real person and legal person in master data service

Tags: sql-server, database, master-data-services, master-data-management

I want to create master data for an organization. I have 5 basic data, one of them is persons. I use the master data service (SQL server). I designed models with the named party and some entities. my entities are Person, organization and Source_relation and another domain base table. I have an attribute in the source_relation table that shows a code. each party has a code and it is in the source_relation table. The person and organization have FOREIGN KEY to source_relation entity. how to design this in master data service? using a unique identifier for the relation between these tables are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that will wise to use  FOREIGN KEY to connect between two tables.

Comment: in the master data service we don't have table and foreign key!! do you use master data service??